# Loop through variable names and set values using for loop

Tags: vb6

I have inherited someone's bad code to try and fix, in this code there are 15 entries per day and are names as follows:

Mon01, Mon02, Mon03, Mon04, etc

I then have a grid with the same number of entries, I need to check if the value of Mon01 matches the first entry in the grid, if not then update its value.  But as I said there are 7 grids so 7*15, so instead of having 105 lines of code i'd rather have 4.

My question is, is there a way to loop through and change the values of these variables.  An example idea is:

```
for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    variable = "Mon" + i
    If (variable.value <> Grid.TextArray(i) Then 
        variable.value = Grid.TextArray(i) 
    End If
End For
```

I know the above isn't valid VB6 code, but its trying to get the message across best way I can.

My current revised code looks like this:

```
DB.Recordsource = "QUERY REMOVED"
Call DB.GetData(RS)

With RS
    Dim ChangeArray() As String

    If Trim(MonGrid.TextArray((1 * MonGrid.Cols) + 2)) <> ![Mon01] Then
        ![Mon01] = MonGrid.TextArray((1 * MonGrid.Cols) + 2)
        ReDim Preserve ChangeArray(0 To UBound(ChangeArray) + 1) As String
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You have my condolences of having to maintain such a horrible codebase.

The answer is that there is no way of doing this in Visual Basic. However, assuming that all `MonXX` variables are of the same type, you could declare `Mon` as an array, and then do a search and replace of `Mon01`, `Mon02`, etc. with `Mon(01)`, `Mon(02)`. You could probably use a decent editor that has regular expressions to match on `Mon(\d\d)` and replace it with `Mon\1` - obviously, depending on how the regex facility works.

Answer (score 0):

You could expose the variables as properties and use the CallByName function, that might help you.  The msdn info is here [CallByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262682%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

it would look something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim m_Mon01 As String
Dim m_Mon02 As String
Dim m_Mon03 As String

Public Property Let Mon01(ByVal strID As String)
    m_Mon01 = strID
End Property

Public Property Let Mon02(ByVal strID As String)
    m_Mon02 = strID
End Property

Public Property Let Mon03(ByVal strID As String)
    m_Mon03 = strID
End Property

Private Sub Command_Click()
    Dim lngIndex  As Long
    Dim strName   As String

    For lngIndex = 1 To 3
        strName = "Mon" + Format$(lngIndex, "00")
        CallByName Me, strName, VbLet, "The value form the grid"
    Next lngIndex
End Sub
```